# What is the correct order of installation for running a DotNet Core web application on a local IIS server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I run a local IIS Server with a DotNot Core 2.1 application deployed to it. I like to keep up to date with the latest security patches that are released monthly and I use the Core download page to do so.

My question is, what ALL do I need to install each time and in what order. I usually find a Framework installer and I chose the SDK just to make I have everything. Then I find a ASPNET.CORE installer and I run those in. Finally, I run the Web Hosting Bundle.

Am I doing too much? Do some of these items copy over the same assets? What is the correct proceedure?

Comment: For .NET Core, all you need is the runtime. You only need to install the hosting bundle again if there's some sort of update to that specifically, but I'm not aware of any that have occurred. The SDK isn't necessary in a server environment - only for local development.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the server bundle does have updates (mostly with security patches), which happened only a few times in the past.

Comment: You probably should go through the announcements repo https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements and get familiar with Microsoft's recommendation on how to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to host an asp.net core web app, follow the [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

In terms of installing things, follow the [Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle)

The bundle will install 3 things:

- .NET Core Runtime
- .NET Core Library
- ASP.NET Core Module (for IIS)